# django url how to specify 2 or more strings

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I want to match the following url

```
 url(r'^home/Physician|Vendor/$, 'ViewerLog', name="monitor_viewerLog"),
```

How do I match Physician or Vendor? Is this the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match Physician or Vendor, use parentheses.

```
url(r'^home/(Physician|Vendor)/$, 'ViewerLog', name="monitor_viewerLog"),
```

This will call your view with the matched value as an argument. If you don't want to capture the matched value, use `(?:...)`.

```
url(r'^home/(?:Physician|Vendor)/$, 'ViewerLog', name="monitor_viewerLog"),
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture the matched value, you can name your returned argument:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<guy>Physician|Vendor)/$', 'ViewerLog', name="monitor_viewerLog"),
```